# Dynamic Methods for Collision Handler in Java

Tags: java, android, collision, game-physics

I want to have a set collision handeler for my game so i dont have to copy alot of code and keep the storage short. In a method i would have in a class, it would look like this for two specific objects.

```
   //Inside collision class     
   public void checkCollision(Block block, Ball ball){
   //do stuff with the variables given
   }
```

This would mean that i can only check collisions for the block + ball

My question is: is it possible to be able to change the object given for example so i can use the same method and just parse in the objects for e.g. the floor object and the ball but sometimes use the block and the ball.

Also sometimes the Floor is not avalible so i cant just parse in block and ball if it wants all three

It would save me having to put in

```
    public void collision(Block block, Floor floor, Ball ball){
    }
```

Please ask if you do not understand,
Many Thanks

Charlton Santana

Answer (score 2):

What if you had a method like this:

```
// ...
public void checkCollision(Collidable a, Collidable b) {
    a.collideWith(b);
}
```

and an interface

```
public interface Collidable {

    SomeReturnType collideWith(Collidable coll);
}
```

In that case you can collide any `Collidable` with another one handling the collision in the `collideWith` method.

This is just an idea it is not yet clear **how** do you want to achieve this effect. So if you extend your answer I can help you further.

Comment: agree with this. I'd write a CollisionHandler class with a static void CheckCollision(Collidable[] objects) method, there you could decide how to partition the objects etcetc...

Answer (score 0):

Overload the methods

```
public void collision(Block block, Floor floor, Ball ball){
   //do stuff
}

public void collision(Floor floor, Ball ball){
   //do stuff
}

public void collision(Block block, Ball ball){
   //do stuff
}
```

Comment: Overloading will lead to a proliferation of overloaded methods. He either have to solve this with inheritance or with the Strategy pattern imho.

Comment: Okay this is fine, i just thought because if i do this i will have to do a method for each level... in each method i will probs have about 50 lines of code and im planning to have alot of levels.

Answer (score 0):

You could use collections and generics like :

```
    public void void checkCollision(List<? extends Collidable> objects) {
    // test whatever you want

}
```

This way you can use the same method to test 2-n object collisions where objects must subclass Collidable class so you keep it type safe instead of using List.

NOTE:There is no reason for this to have tag Android and "Pure Java" users will probably give you more answers. Put maybe API design or something as a tag it's more appropriate.